# Groovy global storing of closures from different scripts

Tags: java, groovy, closures

Is it to possible to store closures from different groovy scripts?
Let's say I have some kind of class that should store the closures:

```
package com.test

class ClosureContainer {
    static closures = [:]

    static def AddClosure(String name, Closure cl) {
        println "Adding closure named ${name}"
        closures[name] = cl
    }
}
```

And then I would like to have groovy scripts that would add closures to it:

```
import com.test.ClosureContainer as container

container.AddClosure("Interesting stuff", {
    println "I'm doing some interesting stuff"
})
```

And later, I should be able to call it like:

```
def closureCode = ClosureContainer.closures["Interesting stuff"]
closureCode()
```

What is the best approach to do it in Groovy? I'm not sure how to handle invoking of the scripts because classes are generated from these scripts.
I'm able to create instances of the scripts during runtime, but I'm not able to retrieve list of the classes/scripts without hardcoding it.

UPDATE:

Let's suppose I have testScript.groovy in package com.test.scripts that adds a few closures to the container. I tried to let the gradle generate classes from the scripts and create instance in the code like this:

```
def className = Class.forName("com.test.scripts.testScript")
def instance = className.newInstance()
instance.run()
```

And I'm hardcoding the testScript name. But there will be a lot of scripts and I should be able to retrieve it dynamically.

Comment: what do you mean by hard coding? which part of your code is hard coded?

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: Oh I understand now in that case you have to use GroovyScriptEngine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended way to run groovy script is to use `GroovyScriptEngine`:

```
String[] path = new String[] { "." };
GroovyScriptEngine engine = new GroovyScriptEngine(path);
engine.run("yoursriptname.groovy", new Binding())
```

NB: `yoursriptname` should be the path of your script relative to `path`.

If you want to pass bindings (arguments and then get the results) you have to use [Binding](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.7/html/gapi/groovy/lang/Binding.html).

Comment: Does that solve the question of storing the closures globally across running multiple scripts?

Comment: I guess I can work with that, so thanks a lot for the response.